# How would I find the minimum non-trivial cut in a graph?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms

I know that there is an algorithm which computes the minimum cut in a graph $G$.

I have a situation where I am trying to compute the minimum *non-trivial* cut of $G$, where I say that a cut is trivial if one of the sides has only one vertex. In other words, I don't want to consider cuts which are merely the set of edges exiting a single vertex.

What is the best algorithm for this problem?

Comment: Suppose that $G$ contains two vertices of degree $1$, and we delete the two edges exiting those vertices. Is this cut nontrivial?

Comment: Yeah, I consider that non-trivial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a starting point that makes $O(n^2)$ calls to a max-flow subroutine:

1. Let $\{v,w\}$ be an arbitrary pair of vertices in $G$. Iterate over pairs of vertices $\{x,y\}$ disjoint from $\{v,w\}$. (If you want both sides of your cut to be connected, then limit $\{v,w\}$ and $\{x,y\}$ to *adjacent* pairs of vertices.)
2. For each case of $\{v,w\}$ and $\{x,y\}$, let $H$ be the graph obtained by contracting $\{v,w\}$ to a single vertex $s$, and contracting $\{x,y\}$ to a single vertex $t$. (We allow double edges out of $s$ and $t$ when $v,w$ or $x,y$ have a common neighbor.) Find a minimum $s,t$-edge cut in $H$.
3. If there is a minimum nontrivial cut in which $v$ and $w$ are on the same side, one of the cases above will find it. So it remains to consider the case where $v$ and $w$ are on opposite sides.
4. For this, iterate over pairs $\{x,y\}$ disjoint from $\{v,w\}$ again, but define $H$ by contracting the pairs $\{v,x\}$ and $\{w,y\}$ instead; otherwise, do exactly what we did in step 2.

Compare this to an algorithm that finds a minimum cut with $O(n)$ calls to a max-flow subroutine, by fixing a vertex $v$ and looking for cuts that separate $v$ from each possible vertex $w$. (That's not the best algorithm out there, but it is pretty good.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This algorithm did occur to me, and it is pretty good. I was hoping to just do some preprocessing on the graph so that the trivial cuts become large, then run a single min-cut computation. I think this might be possible but I'm not sure

Comment: Karger's algorithm would find all connected non-trivial cuts without many changes, but unfortunately it can't possibly find nontrivial cuts like the one with two degree-$1$ vertices :(